# Prove that a function is a nascent delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I need to prove that
$$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}n^2(x-1)+n & x  \in \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n},1\right]\\[6pt] n^2(1-x)+n&x \in \left(1,1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \\[6pt] 0 & x \in \left(0,1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right]\cup\left[1+\dfrac{1}{n},2\right)
\end{cases}
$$
is Dirac Delta distribution at $1$ (i.e. is a nascent delta function). This is:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^2f_n(x)\varphi(x)\,dx=\delta_1=\varphi(1)
\end{equation}

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack! What have you tried? Try to show your attempts

Comment: I did the integral by intervals and then tried using the same approach as for a constant nascent delta function: using the anti derivative and the mean value theorem.

Comment: Did you observe that $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_n(x)\, dx = 1 \text{ ?} \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Let's extend $f_n$ to also be $0$ outside $(0,\,2)$. We want to prove $g_n(x):=f_n(x+1)$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Bbb R} g_n(x) \varphi(x) \, dx=\varphi(0)$. But $g_n(x)=n(1-|nx|)=ng_1(nx)$, so it suffices to verify $g_1$ is a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The test function $\varphi$ is continuous. So for $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $N$ so big that for all $n\ge N,$ for all $x\in(1-\tfrac 1 n, 1 + \tfrac 1 n), \quad$ $\varphi(1)-\varepsilon<\varphi(x)< \varphi(1)+\varepsilon.$ In that case,
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb R} f_n(x) (\varphi(1)-\varepsilon)\, dx \le \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)\varphi(x)\, dx \le \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f_n(x)(\varphi(1)+\varepsilon)\, dx
$$
The values of the first and third integrals above are $\varphi(1)\pm\varepsilon.$